togglePopover() not opens but doesn't close native HTML popover
I'm trying to use HTML's native popover. I've tried using the following JavaScript to toggle the popover on / off.
HTML
<div>
  <button onclick="handlePopover(event, 'popover-1')">+</button>
  <aside id="popover-1" popover="">
    <p>My Test</p>
  </aside>
</div>

JavaScript
function handlePopover(event, id) {
  // Identify the first popover element with the given id
  const popover = document.getElementById(id)

  // Exit early if no matching popover was found
  if (!popover) return

  // Get the coordinates of the clicked button
  let rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect()

  // Modify the coordinates of the popover
  popover.style.left = rect.left + 10 + "px"
  popover.style.top = rect.top + 10 + "px"

  // Toggle the display state
  popover.togglePopover()
}

The popover toggles on correctly, and it is positioned correctly. However, it does not toggle off when I click the button a second (or third, or fourth..) time. Note however that the popover does disappear if I click outside the popover area AND not on top the button.
How do I hide the popover when the button is clicked a second time?

Demo
Without Custom event handler
You can do it easily using popovertarget attribute
<div>
  <button popovertarget="popover-1">+</button>
  <aside id="popover-1" popover>
    <p>My Test</p>
  </aside>
</div>

With Custom Event handler
Using manual popover state
If you want to use a custom event for this use following with popover="manual"
 <aside id="popover-1" popover="manual">
    <p>My Test</p>
  </aside>


Notice how my JavaScript code modifies the position of the popover. I would like to retain that functionality. That's why I think it's cleaner to handle all the popover logic inside a single JS function.

popover="manual" seems to be the solution. Although, with "manual", I lose some nice out-of-the-box functionality, like clicking off the popover to hide it and only showing one popover at a time. Thanks

you can also do something like this:
a) give your button an id
 <button id="popOverId" onclick="handlePopover(event, 'popover-1')">+</button>

b) toggle popOver when the button is clicked
    let toggle = true;
    
    function handlePopover(event, id) {
        // Identify the first popover element with the given id
        const popover = document.getElementById(id)
    
        // Exit early if no matching popover was found
        if (!popover) return
    
        // Get the coordinates of the clicked button
        let rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect()
    
        // Modify the coordinates of the popover
        popover.style.left = rect.left + 10 + "px"
        popover.style.top = rect.top + 10 + "px"
    
        // Toggle the display state
        popover.togglePopover(toggle);
    
    }
    
    
    document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
    
        if (evt.target.id !== "popOverId") {
            toggle = true;
        } else {
            toggle = !toggle;
        }
    
    });

underscore's solution is more concise and clean, so if it covers your needs, it's the one to pick.
